# Android - Listen for key presses on Numeric keypad?

Tags: android, keycode, keyevent, android-softkeyboard, numeric-keypad

I use the following code to listen for the key presses of 0 - 9 from the soft input keyboard on Android:

---

```
@Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0)
            {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1)
            {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2)
            {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3)
            {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_4)
            {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5)
            {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_6)
            {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_7)
            {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_8)
            {
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }

            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9)
            {
                Log.d("Keycode", "Got KeyCode 9");
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

---

The code works when i display the soft input keyboard in the following mode:

[image]

However it does **not** work when I display the soft input keyboard in the following mode:

[image]

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because there are different keycodes for the number pad. Unfortunately they were only introduced in API Level 11 (android 3.0, honeycomb) so you will have to find another way to address those guys for maximum compatibility.

Comment: You can isolate the input by using android:digits="0123456789" in the xml file for those particular textviews. You don't need any error handling code in the java after this is done.